# Confused with probabilistic notation and precedence

Tags: probability, notation, conditional-probability

Is $P(A|B,C) = P(A|(B \cap C))$ or $P((A|B) \cap C)$?

In my book they do something like this in a proof regarding Markov models:

$P(A|B_{1:t+1}) = P(A|B_{1:t},B_{t+1}) = P(B_{t+1}|A,B_{1:t})*P(A|B_{1:t})$/$P(B_{1:t+1})$

And I'm totally confused. Could someone write this out with parenthesis and $\cap/\cup$?

edit: Removed the $\alpha$

Comment: The "invention" P((A|B)∩C) was already asked about some while ago, was it by you?

Comment: Nope, this is my first post here. Excuse my ignorance :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever $P(B\cap C)>0$ you have
$$
P(A\mid B,C)=P(A\mid B\cap C)=P(A\cap B\cap C)/P(B\cap C).
$$
The "quantity" $P((A\mid B)\cap C)$ is nonsense, since $A\mid B$ isn't a set.

Comment: Alright, that's what I originally thought, however the proof from my book made me unsure (probably irrationally, but either way), and still makes no sense to me. I don't understand how they get the third term.

Comment: I don't either since and probably won't until you define what $A,B_{1:t},B_{t+1},B_{1:t+1}$ and $\alpha$ is.

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't sure if that was standard notation. A is just a random variables, $B_{1:t}$ is a set of events from 1 to t, and $B_{t+1}$ is event t+1. $B_{1:t}$ and $B_{t+1}$ is just a partition of a set of events ranging from 1 to t+1. In my book they say they use Bayes' for the third step, but I don't understand how.  $\alpha$ is 1/$P(B_{1:t+1})$ I believe.

Comment: I probably should've just posted that second "problem" as it's own question with a little more thought put into the presentation...

Comment: Is $B_{t+1}$ and $B_1\cap\cdots\cap B_t$ independent? Furthermore, $A$ must be a set, not a random variable.

Comment: Yes, a is a set, my bad. All the B's are independent yes. They depend only on A.

Comment: Then I urge you try again with the right-hand side. Use the definition of conditional probability and use the independence assumption. Then you should be able to arrive at $P(A\mid B_{1:t},B_{t+1})$. When you have done that, you should post this as an answer here. Let me know if you're stuck.

Comment: I realize that I've probably screwed this up quite bad, so I'll just provide a picture of what's in my book: http://i.imgur.com/2I5WiBw.jpg I just tried to simply it for the question, but I suppose I just ended up obfuscating it. Sorry! I'm new to this.